# MariaDB 5.5 -- how to customize password rules

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.5, mariadb-5.5

I am using RHEL 7, which includes MariaDB 5.5.

I want to set up minimum requirements for passwords: minimums length 15, 1 lowercase, 1 uppercase, 1 symbol, 1 number.

I figure that I am probably not the first person using Rhel 7 to face this problem.  **Does anyone have some guidance on the best approach to add the above password rules to MariaDB 5.5 under Rhel 7?**

I have so far pieced together these facts.  (Some I am not so sure are correct.)  I believe these facts indicate my best option is to just do whatever 5.5. allows.

- MariaDB 5.5 doesn't do this. There is no plugin.
- MariaDB 5.7
  introduced new password features.
- MariaDB 10.1 and later has password
  plugin with this functionality.
- Installing an updated MariaDB on Rhel
  7 would requiring making my own RPM and possibly put the system
  security at risk.
- I could write my own password routines and put them
  in the database.  But this is not recommended, because it is easy to
  introduce a security flaw.
- I can configure 5.5 to work with Linux's
  PAM, or use the standard linux-user-name-matches-the-mysql-account-name authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments:

- Re: "the standard linux-user-name-matches-the-mysql-account-name authentication" - I assume you mean using the [`unix_socket`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/documentation/columns-storage-engines-and-plugins/plugins/authentication-plugins/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) plugin for authentication. This only works on localhost, i.e. the user has to be logged in on the database server.
- There is no MariaDB 5.7, but there is however a MySQL 5.7.
- There is no need to build your own RPM for MariaDB 10.x on RHEL7. You can just add the relevant MariaDB 10.x .repo file to your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. You can use the [repo config tool on mariadb.org](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/).

It's up to you to decide whether it's worth the effort to upgrade to MariaDB 10.1+ and thereby be able to use the password checking plugins - [`simple_password_check`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/documentation/columns-storage-engines-and-plugins/plugins/password-validation-plugins/simple-password-check-plugin/) and [`cracklib_password_check`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/documentation/columns-storage-engines-and-plugins/plugins/password-validation-plugins/cracklib-password-check-plugin/). (10.4 is now GA, though at the moment this is still relatively new, so you may want to consider 10.3 or older as a more stable release.)

Comment: +1  Apparently I am a plebe here and I can't upvote :(

Comment: @BAMF4bacon I upvoted for you.